# SQL Server trigger based audit table with comparisons for specific columns

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I will try to explain my problem as basic as possible:

I have two tables: `Foo` and `Foo_Audit`.

On row update I want to copy the row to the `Foo_Audit` table, but only if the value of `Foo.Bar` or `Foo.Qux` changes. `Foo.Baz` needs to be **ignored**.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Foo_Modified 
ON Foo 
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    DECLARE @rowCount int  

    SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*) 
    FROM (SELECT Bar, Qux 
          FROM inserted  
          EXCEPT  
          SELECT Bar, Qux 
          FROM deleted) #TempTable

    IF (@rowCount > 0)  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO Foo_Audit(Bar, Qux, Baz)  
            SELECT 
                Bar, Qux, Baz 
            FROM Foo  
END
```

Everything works perfectly fine, if I test it by updating just one row at the time. But when multiple rows are updated at the same time (~400), it sometime adds the same row multiple times to the `Foo_Audit` table and it adds the row even if the value of `Foo.Bar` or `Foo.Qux` hasn't changed.

Does anyone know, how to make my code work on multiple row-updates at the same time? And by the same time I mean same millisecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Foo_Modified 
ON Foo 
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    DECLARE @rowCount int  

    INSERT INTO dbo.Foo_Audit(Bar, Qux, Baz)  
        SELECT 
            i.Bar, i.Qux, i.Baz 
        FROM 
            Inserted i
        INNER JOIN
            Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
        WHERE 
            i.Bar <> d.Bar
            OR .Qux <> d.Qux
```

Basically, just insert any rows into your audit table if `bar` or `qux` have been modified between the `Deleted` pseudo table (with the old values *before* the `UPDATE`) and the `Inserted` pseudo table (with the new values *after* the `UPDATE`).

This should work just fine for any number of rows being updated at once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works like a charm! Greetings from Basel :)